# C# Socket.send is very slow

Tags: c#, performance, sockets, arrays

I'm using `Socket` class to send image data in byte array to the third-party programm running on the same PC (so I don't have to worry about connection problems). Since I have really simple application, I use only synchronous `send(bytes)` function and nothing more. The problem is, it runs very slow. If I send a small 20kB picture, it takes near 15ms, but if a picture is large enought - 1.5mB, it takes near 800ms, which is unacceptable for me. How can I improve socket performance?

```
Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3998);
sender.Connect(remoteEP);

byte[] imgBytes;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Image img = Image.FromFile("С:\img.bmp");
img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
imgBytes = ms.ToArray();
/*Some byte operations there: adding headers, file description and other stuff.
They are really fast and add just 10-30 bytes to array, so I don't post them*/

DateTime baseDate = DateTime.Now; // Countdown start

for (uint i = 0; i < 100; i++) sender.Send(byteMsg);

TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - baseDate; 
Debug.Print("End: " + diff.TotalMilliseconds);
// 77561 for 1.42mB image, 20209 for 365kb, 1036 for 22kB.
```

Comment: Can you show how your sending the image?

Comment: Are you benchmarking the right thing? That is, only the `sender.Send`?

Comment: No, I send data multiple times.

Comment: @Martijn yes I do. I've tried to extract bytes once and then send them many times, calling `sender.Send(imgBytes)` only. And it takes nearly 800ms per iteration.

Comment: Any difference in perf if you use 127.0.0.1 for the remote endpoint?

Comment: @mxmissile not even a percent.

Comment: Are you able to test the ability of the end point to receive? Bottleneck could be there perhaps?

Comment: I cannot trace anything on the other side, because it's a CCV modification with socket transport support (https://github.com/devintCo/ccv15_dvn). But I can write a simple socket server on C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on the other side. I'm using [CCV socket modification](http://github.com/devintCo/ccv15_dvn) as a server and it seems, this programm makes lots of operations even while receiving a picture. I've tried my code from question with test server app ([Synchronous Server Socket Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3(v=vs.110).aspx) from Microsoft and removed string analysis from it) and since this everything start working near 100 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

This may be reading a big file to memory stream, copying it to an array and then reallocating that array to prepend it with some data, which actually affects the performance, and not the Socket.send().

Try using stream to stream copy approach:

```
        Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3998);
        sender.Connect(remoteEP);
        using (var networkStream = new NetworkStream(sender))
        {
            // Some byte operations there: adding headers, file description and other stuff.
            // These should sent here by virtue of writing bytes (array) to the networkStream

            // Then send your file
            using (var fileStream = File.Open(@"С:\img.bmp", FileMode.Open))
            {
                // .NET 4.0+
                fileStream.CopyTo(networkStream);

                // older .NET versions
                /*
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int read;
                while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                */
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's definitely `Socket.send()` who kills the performance. I've updated my post to make this obvious.